# C++, ejectuar binario desde un byte array

Tags: c++, array, puntero-a-función

estoy tratando de usar punteros a función apuntando a un binario almacenado en byte array, pero siempre me resulta en segmentation fault.

```
unsigned char byteProg[] = {0x7F,0x45,0x4C,0x46,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,.......};

int main()

{

    int (*func_ptr)(void);

    func_ptr= (int (*)(void)) byteProg;

    (*func_ptr)();


    return 0;
}

i also tried with no luck:

typedef unsigned char uchar;

void func(void)
{

    printf("Hello\n");

}


void next_func_sector(void)

{


}


int main()

{
    uchar func_buff[0x1000];

    void (*prg)(void);


    memcpy(func_buff, (void *) func, ((uchar *) next_func_sector - (uchar *) func));


    prg= (void (*)(void)) func_buff;

    (*prg)();


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hola dante, bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Podrías ser tan amable de traducir tu pregunta?

Comment: Ahí esta, litooo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer es comportamiento indefinido.
El standard de C++ no da ninguna garantía acerca de lo que haría ese programa.

Lo cual no quiere decir que no puedas hacerlo. Incluso puede ser útil.
Pero lo que haga el programa dependerá del compilador que uses y del sistema operativo en que se ejecute el programa. Un programa que hace esto puede que funcione al compilarlo con un compilador pero puede que no funcione con otro, incluso puede que no funcione con otras versiones del mismo compilador.

En cuanto a las causas del segmentation fault, los sitemas operativos modernos tienen mecanismos de protección de ejecución de áreas de memoria. Estos sistemas impiden que se ejecuten instrucciones en áreas marcadas para datos, lo cual aumenta la seguridad del sistema. Seguramente tu array `byteProg` se encuentra en esa situación y por eso el programa se interrumpe cuando se detecta esa violación de seguridad.
Hay formas de marcar zonas de memoria para que se puedan ejecutar. Pero la forma de hacerlo depende de cada sistema operativo.